# How do I find all lines not containing a specific word?

Tags: python, regex

In my case I want to find (using python regex) all lines **not** containing the words "error" or "empty". In code:

> varformals    : PAR_OPEN PAR_CLOSE                                                    {}
>             | PAR_OPEN varform PAR_CLOSE                                            {}
>   /* error */ | error PAR_CLOSE                                                     {}
>
>   /* error */ | error varform PAR_CLOSE                                             {}
>
>   /* error */ | PAR_OPEN error PAR_CLOSE                                                {}
>   ;

Comment: Does it have to be with `regex` ?

Comment: The use of regex makes sense, I'm pretty sure this is a duplicate, make edits if you believe this is not the case.

Comment: Actually "Python Regex" is different from regex. (pythex simulator[pythex.org])
Also I prefer a "python regex", but if you have a good alternative please post. :D

Answer (score 1):

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/jL7jT1/2)

```
(^((?!error|empty).)*$)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/nY4tBGJ1VcyxjFV2)

**description**

```
1st Capturing group (^((?!error|empty).)*$)
    ^ assert position at start of a line
2nd Capturing group ((?!error|empty).)*
    Quantifier: * Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
    Note: A repeated capturing group will only capture the last iteration.
    Put a capturing group around the repeated group to capture all 
    iterations or use a non-capturing group instead if you're not interested 
    in the data
    (?!error|empty) Negative Lookahead - Assert that it is impossible to match the regex below
        1st Alternative: error
            error matches the characters error literally (case sensitive)
        2nd Alternative: empty
            empty matches the characters empty literally (case sensitive)
    . matches any character (except newline)
$ assert position at end of a line
g modifier: global. All matches (don't return on first match)
m modifier: multi-line. Causes ^ and $ to match the begin/end of each line (not only begin/end of string)
```

Comment: Only the word 'empty' is missing as in OP's question: `(?!error|empty)`

Comment: @agold thanks for pointing that out, updated answer

Comment: First I also thought this was the answer, but this regular regex statement apparently don't work with python regex.
(to test see: pythex.org)

Comment: @HackSlash i just went to pythex.org and it works exactly the same you need to enable the multi-line flag